# Version,version major,version minor SSIS Package properties

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Under the properties of a ssis package we have a section which  include version,Version major,version minor etc. Can some one explain me what is the use of these properties?
I found that version number keeps on increasing every time we modify the package 
and also it can be edited to any value

Comment: What is missing from the documentation that you still need explained?   Can you expand on your question to make it more clear?

Comment: I created a simple ssis Package which has one dft.When i see the properties of package I found these properties ,need to know the use of them. I am using SSIS 2012 version

Comment: The use is explained on MSDN.

Comment: What exactly is not clear?   Can you post a sentence from MSDN that you don't understand?

Comment: I need the use of these ,it seams like they provide the name itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115115/discussion-between-n-dinesh-reddy-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 3):

Every time you *save* an SSIS package within Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT, the Version Build and Version GUID are updated. VersionBuild is a monotonically increasing number and the GUID is a guid doing whatever they do to generate a new one.

Version Major, Version Minor and Version Comments are there for you. If you are in a shop that creates [specific builds](http://semver.org/) of your products, then you can align the values in your SSIS packages with those.

I have set major/minor when I am programatically "fixing" packages. Once I added all my auditing stuff, I'd assign a major/minor so that when I re-ran my code, it could detect it had already fixed the package and abort out early